# Refresh a dynamic range in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

This is most likely a basic question for you, I learned vba on my own so I am lacking some fundamentals for sure.

I got a simulation spreadsheet that calculates returns. The number of simulations is not constant, so I only want to refresh one part of the spreadsheet. My code is this:

```
Worksheets("Monte Carlo").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(4 + MaxN, 1001)).Calculate
```

Returns an error.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try resizing instead of performing the math inside the Cells:

```
Worksheets("Monte Carlo").Cells(1,1).resize(4 + MaxN, 1001).Calculate
```

If that fails, try using a range object

```
Dim rngData as Range
Set rngData = Worksheets("Monte Carlo").Cells(1,1).resize(4 + MaxN, 1001)
rngData.Calculate
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work (tested on my system):

```
Dim MaxN As Long

With Worksheets("Monte Carlo")
    MaxN = .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(MaxN, 1001)).Calculate
End With
```

Note, that your `Range` ends at row `MaxN` (no need to add 4 here as `MaxN` is already the last row) and in column 1001 (!!) which equates to column ALM. So, you need to make sure that you are running this macro only while having an Excel file open which supports that many columns (Version 2007+ and **not** in compatibility mode).